# Host an ASP.Net Core 6 Razor pages app within a WPF desktop application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I have a WPF desktop application used to control industrial machinery, and I'd like to expose a subset of its functionality via a website to allow basic control and monitoring of the machinery if (say) the operator is away from the lab.

I've added an ASP.Net Razor Pages project to my solution (which for now includes the usual boilerplate stuff like index.cshtml "welcome" page). To keep things simple, the web app project references the desktop app's "application logic" project, allowing it to access the required functionality directly. The desktop app will need to be running though for this to work.

`Program.cs` is more or less out-of-the-box but modified very slightly to allow me to stop the web app when the desktop app closes:

```
public static class Program
{
    private static WebApplication _app;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

        builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        _app = builder.Build();

        // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        if (!_app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            _app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }
        _app.UseStaticFiles();
        _app.UseRouting();
        _app.UseAuthorization();
        _app.MapRazorPages();
        _app.Run();
    }

    public static void Stop()
    {
        _app.StopAsync();
    }
}
```

My desktop app's "bootstrapper" starts the web app by calling `Task.Run(() => Program.Main(null));`, and stops the web app by calling `Program.Stop()` when the desktop app is closing.

I have also added the following section to `appsettings.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
  "Endpoints": {
    "Https": {
      "Url": "https://localhost:8888"
    }
  }
},
```

This was necessary as I noticed that the web app hosting environment is "Production" (for some reason?), so wasn't picking up the settings from launchSettings.json.

There are no errors when I start the desktop app, and I see the following in the VS output window:

```
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Now listening on: https://localhost:8888
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Hosting environment: Production
Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime: Information: Content root path: C:\...path to desktop app's bin folder...
```

However when I try to browse https://localhost:8888 I get a 404 error. Any thoughts on what is going wrong? I'm very new to ASP.Net Core, but gut feeling is this has something to do with wwwroot and Pages folders being in the "wrong" place. I tried copying these to the desktop app's bin folder but that didn't help - I guess there is more to it than that.

(Note, the web app project is working and browsable if I run it as the VS startup project).

Answer (score 1):

Sorted. The key was to create the builder using the following syntax, specifying an environment of `Development`:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(new WebApplicationOptions
    {
        Args = args,
        ApplicationName = typeof(Program).Assembly.FullName,
        ContentRootPath = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(),
        WebRootPath = "wwwroot",
        EnvironmentName = Environments.Development,
    });
```

Additionally, the build output of the WPF desktop app (which is the VS startup project) becomes the web application's "content root". It was therefore necessary to add a post-build script to the web app project to copy the wwwroot folder to the desktop app's build output folder, otherwise it can't serve up any static web content.